# Android/Linux PDF/eBook reader with horizontal scrolling feature instead of vertical

Tags: android, linux, pdf-viewer, ebooks, cloud

So far, all the readers I experienced scroll pages vertically while fitting horizontally A4 pages' width.

Are there softwares out there able to:

1. "swipe left" pages
2. fit vertically both A4 and A3 pages (which have the same height) to the portrait-oriented screen
3. compatible with Linux and Android
4. must have would be some comment-stick/highlight/draw-on features
5. cherry on the top would be integrated sync to both centralized and self-hosted clouds
   ?

Sometimes PDF files include portrait-oriented A4 pages, with landscape-oriented A3 pages, and it's a pain in the ass having to resize at each switch...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try **Xodo**:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en&gl=US

- You can change between Vertical/Horizontal scrolling.
- You can enable "RTL mode" to swipe left (if I understood correctly)
- Currently no Linux app, but you can use the web app version. ([pdf.online](https://pdf.online))
- Has Annotation features